# Does $\dot{\theta}^2=-\frac{g}{l}\cos\theta\iff\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$ holds? (Simple pendulum problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

[image: simple pendulum]

I solved a simple pendulum problem as follows (please see the above figure):

By the Newton's second law,

$$m\ddot{\vec{r}}=-ml\dot{\theta}^2\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta \\ \sin\theta\end{pmatrix}+ml\ddot{\theta}\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta \\ \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}=mg\cos\theta\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta \\ \sin\theta\end{pmatrix}-mg\sin\theta\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta \\ \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}.$$
From this equation, we get the following two differential equations:
$\dot{\theta}^2=-\frac{g}{l}\cos\theta.$
$\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta.$

If $\theta$ satisfies $\dot{\theta}^2=-\frac{g}{l}\cos\theta$, then does $\theta$ satisfy $\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$?
If $\theta$ satisfies $\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$, then does $\theta$ satisfy $\dot{\theta}^2=-\frac{g}{l}\cos\theta$?

Comment: What happens if you differentiate the equation in $\dot\theta$ with respect to time?

Comment: @TravisWillse Thank you very much for your comment. I forgot the tension $T$. Sorry.

Comment: From the equation $\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$ we get $\theta(t)$. And from the equation $-ml\dot{\theta}^2=mg\cos\theta-T(t)$ we get the tension $T(t)$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derived equations do not account for the tension ${\bf T}$ constraining the bob. Conveniently, though, this means that we can describe our system correctly with a single degree of freedom.

If we denote the angular displacement by $\theta$, the displacement along the arc of radius $l$ centered at the top of the pendulum is $l \theta$, and so its tangential acceleration is $l \ddot\theta$. Drawing a right triangle shows that the tangential force is $-mg \sin \theta$ (and, incidentally, $T = mg \cos\theta$, though we don't need that fact to derive the equation of motion). Now, Newton's Second Law gives that
$$m l \ddot \theta = -mg \sin \theta,$$
and canceling and rearranging gives the classical pendulum equation,
$$\ddot\theta = -\frac{g}{l} \sin \theta .$$
To recover an equation in $\dot\theta$, we can multiply both sides by $\dot\theta$ and integrate, yielding
$$\frac{1}{2} \dot\theta^2 = \frac{g}{l} (\cos \theta + C)$$
for some constant $C$ that we can express, e.g., in terms of the energy of the system or the maximum angular displacement.

Comment: Travis Willse, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, not really.

I noticed that your formula for pendulum is not correct. You might mean these:
$$\frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{2} = \frac{g}{l} \cos(\theta)$$
and
$$\ddot{\theta} = -\frac{g}{l} \sin(\theta)$$

The trivial counterexample is $\theta \equiv \pi /2$, where $\dot{\theta}^2/2=\frac{g}{l}\cos\theta = 0$
but $\ddot{\theta}=0 \ne -\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$.

In that case, you may assume that $\theta$ is not a constant.

By taking derivative, you get
$\ddot{\theta}\dot{\theta}=\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta \dot{\theta}$ and you can cancel $\dot{\theta}$ because $\theta$ is not a constant, then you get  $\ddot{\theta} = -\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$. However, if you have $\ddot{\theta} = -\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$, then you can't get $\frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{2} = \frac{g}{l} \cos(\theta)$, because actually $\frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{2} = \frac{g}{l} \cos(\theta) + C$.

Comment: Zhang Ruichong, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you very much for your comment.